# Is there a way to make sure that a class overrides hashCode

Tags: scala

I am creating a cache, and want to make sure that the key type overrides hashCode. 
If hashCode was not already defined on Object, something like this would work

```
trait Key {
  def hashCode: Int
}
```

If the keys are always case classes it is obviously not a problem, but I want to make sure that if somebody passes a regular class it will fail. Is there a way to do it in Scala?

On a side note: My key is specifications for a SQL query which currently is represented as case classes. For example

```
case class Filter(age: Option[Int], gender: Option[String])
```

But eventually, I want to represent it using a cleaner specification pattern implementation  (for example: https://gist.github.com/lbialy/912fad3c909374b81ce7)

Comment: How would you enforce the requirement that `equals()` being `true` implies `hashCode()` values are equal? You have launched yourself on a slippery slope here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to explicitly whitelist classes that are allowed to use their `hashCode`, you cannot use inheritance for that, but you can provide your own typeclass:

```
trait HasApprovedHashCode[X] {
  def hashCode(x: X): Int
}
```

and then modify all the methods that crucially rely on a proper implementation of `hashCode` like this:

```
def methodRelyingOnHashCode[K: HasApprovedHashCode, V](...) = ...
```

Now you can explicitly whitelist only those classes that you deem as having good enough implementation of `hashCode`.

Usually, I would say: hash code of the used key is not your responsibility. If the user of your library insists on shooting h(im/er)self in the foot, you cannot prevent it. You shouldn't facilitate it, or even create a situation where this is almost inevitable, but it's not your responsibility to hunt down every single class out there that could somehow misbehave when used as a key of a map.