# How to implement a collection of key, value pairs with mixed but restricted types for values

Tags: scala, typeclass, generic-collections

A use case here is to imagine a config object, that is a collection of key-value pairs.

I would like a to create a type representing this collection of key, value pairs. And I'd also like to have the values be of varied types. Further, I'd like to keep those key, value pairs in a single collection, despite the values being of different types. But I don't want to allow the values to by of any type at all. Finally, I'd like to be able to recover the value for a given key. (Bonus points, I'd like to ensure keys are unique)

Something like:

```
trait Property
case class SProperty(name: String, value:String) extends Property
case class DProperty(name: String, value:Double) extends Property
case class IProperty(name: String, value:Int) extends Property

case class Properties(props: List[Property]) {
  def getValueByName(name: String) = {
    props.find(p => p.name == name).map(p => p.value)
  } 
}
```

And this works ok, but it creates an ugly API. For example:

```
val properties = Properties(
  List(
    Property("some name", "some value"),
    Property("another name", "another value")
  )
)
```

If I have a test that checks:

```
properties.getValueByName("some name").getOrElse(None) shouldBe "some value"
```

the test will fail with

```
SProperty("some value") is not equal to "some value"
```

I considered using a shapeless HList, however that would allow `Properties` to take on any type. I only want `Property` types in the collection, and I want the values in those to be restricted to types `String | Double | Int`.

Is there a better way to define this collection of key, value pairs that allows for a specific set of value types and that can provide me with a `.get` method?

Is there a better way to define my `getValueByName` method such that it returns the underlying value and not the wrapped value?

One approach is to write the getter like this:

```
def getValueByName[T](name: String): Option[Any] = {
  Properties.find(p => p.name == name).map {
    case Property(_, SProperty(v)) => Some(v)
    case Property(_, DProperty(v)) => Some(v)
    case Property(_, IProperty(v)) => Some(v)
    case _ => None
}
```

}

But this starts to be a lot of places to modify the code to add a new type allowed for the property values. Returning an `Option[Any]` seems wrong. And to use the getter, you'd need to know the type of the value ahead of time. That may be good, but it may be a hassle.

I was also unable to find an acceptable approach using typeclasses, but I admit that I'm not deeply experienced with writing typeclasses.

Comment: 1) If you want unique keys, then why are you storing properties in a `List`, not a `Map`? 2) It's unclear how the test could fail with `"SProperty("some value")"` in the message. Shouldn't it be `Some("some value")` instead? Also, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49309024/is-there-a-way-to-make-sure-that-a-class-overrides-hashcode/49309445#49309445) about explicitly white-listing selected classes by providing typeclass instances.

Comment: Look at shapeless records perhaps?

Comment: @AndreyTyukin Good catch on the test. I corrected the example there. If each Property is a Map instead of a case class, that still won't ensure uniqueness across Properties. And I don't want the collection to be of type Map[String, Any]

Comment: @Daenyth do records allow for restricting the types of the values? I'm not seeing that capability in the documentation I've found.

Comment: @Metropolis Records associate a specific type to each individual key. If that's not what you want, consider using a coproduct?

Comment: Why would you prefer a general `getValueByName` retrieval method than some adhoc overloading, e.g. `Option[Int] getIntByName`, `Option[String] getStringByName`, etc? Your selection of allowed types seems to be adhoc, hence, there will be no general client who need a general getter.

Comment: You could use typesafe-config (https://github.com/lightbend/config) to load hocon file and present them as case-classes. Using hocon enables you to create hierarchy that can be configured by specifying the full-key-name such as A.B.C.D or to create an hierarchy.
The defaults can be set in the case-classes, and you can create a chain of fallbacks so it searches for a key along this chain.

Comment: I would analyze the underlying requirements of the problem you are trying to solve to determine if your approach is necessary.  You are trying to use a strongly typed language, scala, to do dynamic typing.  This suggests a general flaw to your approach.  For example, can each of your properties go into a separate `Map`?  There may be a correct answer to your question, but it may not be the correct answer to your problem...